# Как отфильтровать диапазон ячеек по значению в Google-таблице через Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Это мой первый опыт написания кода:). Пишу на `GAS` `Telegram`-бота, запутался в методах `GAS` и никак не могу разобраться как отфильтровать определённый диапазон ячеек на соответствие определённому значению?
Я пока понял только как назначить диапазон для фильтра:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B");
var filter = range.createFilter();
```

А вот как задать условие для поиска ячейки - ума не приложу:(.

Comment: Пожалуйста переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: Подкорректировал

Answer (score 0):

`createFilter` оперирует с фильтрами в Таблице. Не уверен, что это то, что вам нужно для бота.

Пожалуй, работа с обычным JS будет куда практичнее

```js
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:D");
var values = range.getValues();
var data = values.filter(function(row){
  return row[1] == 'YES';
})
```

код выше возвращает двумерный массив из строк, в которых в `B` находится текст `YES`;

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!